How do I filter drops in a PPG signal?
My PPG signals are usually pretty clean. But every once in a while I get what looks like a photodiode threshold peak and the signal drops, then continues on perfectly. I applied linear regression de-trending but it is still there. What can I do next to smooth this signal out? The actual values are not critical so if I were to find the delta and subtract from the larger set or something like that, it is OK. This happens at various points, so I'l like a Scipy call to some sort of filter to just remove it if possible. Thanks for any suggestions...
PPG signal. First 10-12 seconds are warm up and are ignored.


If the values don’t matter, why do you want to smooth the signal out?

because when I apply other filters it causes bumps. I need to also apply butterworth and savitzky-golay and then I get weird spikes in the data.

Sounds to me like you need a pretty simple high-pass filter; something with an impulse response like 1/N · [-1, -1, …, -1, +1, …, +1, +1]. That should remain nice and well-behaved a lot, close to zero (it's after all just seeing the difference between the average of N/2 older and the next N/2 samples). But at the very point it gets applied to your drops, you should suddenly see a sharp spike – super easy and robust to detect with a simple if output >= N/3 or something.

Thanks. You are right. I did this in PHP. Didn't even need Scipy. Then I just removed that one spike that remained.

I mean, PHP, still the slowest thing you can do math in, but: Happy you got it to work!
